# How to generate each week list from date range (start date and end date)?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have start date as Monday of any month and end date as Sunday of any month. I need week list which falls between dates. For e.g. I  have selected start date as 08/12/2019 and end date as 09/08/2019. As a output, require list of week. So

```
{[08/12/2019,08/13/2019,08/14/2019,08/15/2019,08/16/2019,08/17/2019,08/18/2019],[08/19/2019,08/20/2019,08/21/2019,08/22/2019,08/23/2019,08/24/2019,08/25/2019],[08/26/2019,08/27/2019,08/28/2019,08/29/2019,08/30/2019,08/31/2019,09/01/2019],[09/02/2019,09/03/2019,09/04/2019,09/05/2019,09/06/2019,09/07/2019,09/08/2019]}
```

Require in react hook/js.

```
var start = new Date("08/12/2019");
var end = new Date("09/08/2019");
var newStart = start.setDate(start.getDate()+7);

var days = [];
for (var d = begin; d <= newStart; d = d + 1) {
   days.push(new Date(d));
 }
```

this only works for 1 week, not so much helpful.

Comment: Okay, sounds like a challenge. What code have you written to meet the challenge? Where are you stuck?

Comment: var start = new Date("08/12/2019");
var end = new Date("09/08/2019");
var newStart = start.setDate(start.getDate()+7);


var days = [];
for (var d = begin; d <= newStart; d = d + 1) {
   days.push(new Date(d));
}

it works for first week only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would be great, if anyone can help

Comment: please note `start.setDate()` will modify the `start` variable to a different Date value and it will return a number of milliseconds - not sure if that is intentional, but it is a potential bug to be aware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your solution by using a nested loop:

```js
const start = new Date("2019-08-12");
const end = new Date("2019-09-08");

const DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

const weeks = [];
for (let newStart = start.valueOf(); newStart < end; newStart += DAY * 7) {
  const days = [];
  for (let d = newStart; d < newStart + 7 * DAY; d += DAY) {
    days.push(new Date(d));
  }
  weeks.push(days);
}

console.log(weeks);
```

Notes:

- I used the standard [Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) `YYYY-MM-DD` for zero time offset from UTC, to avoid random time offsets

  - `new Date(d).toJSON().slice(0, 10)` will convert a Date back to string in this format
- I used [.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) to convert a Date to number for correct behaviour of the `+` operator

  - note that `d + 1` with a Date object will convert it to string and concatenates it with '1', so I am using `d` as a Number to make sure `+` is a number addition
  - `d += DAY` is the same as `d = d + DAY`
- I used [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for proper block scope inside `for` (`var` would declare the variable in function scope)
- I did not handle edge cases (different types instead of Date, infinite end, wrong days of week, ...)

Comment: *From MDN:* "Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."

Comment: Also why rewrite OP's original loop (manipulating `Date`s directly) with timestamp arithmetic, since they mentioned it already works? (if it was wrong please explain)

Comment: @hugo the second half of that MDN warning is: `Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.` - which is desired behaviour in this answer and it works the same way even in IE11. `begin` is undefined in the OP's code and adding 1 to a Date object is a string concatenation, so something might "work" for the OP but they didn't post runnable code (I updated my answer to include a note about `d + 1`)

Comment: You’re right, I should have read the warning closer! As for the `d+1`, it’s hard to tell if OP's adding to a date since, as you noted, we don’t see the initialization of `begin`... But seeing the way they use `d`, it has to be wrong indeed — I think the intent was to increment a day number initialized with `startDate.getDate()`, and applying it with `setDate` (as done in the 3rd line of OP's code) — which would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The second simple way is like below where you don't need to use double loops.

```js
function getWeeks(startDate, endDate){
  var sd = new Date(startDate);
var weeks = [];
  var week = [];
  var weekCounter = 1; // you can remove this
for (var d = sd; d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    week.push(new Date(d).getMonth()+1 +'/'+new Date(d).getDate()+'/'+new Date(d).getFullYear());
  if(new Date(d).getDay() == 0)
    {
      weeks.push("Week"+weekCounter + ":"); // you can remove this
      weeks.push(week); 
      weekCounter++; // you can remove this
      week = [];
    }
}
  return weeks;
}
console.log(getWeeks('08/12/2019','09/08/2019'));
```